# Update field in table with the max value in another table, with the foreign key

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to update a "mostRecentDate" field in one table with the max date in another table with the same key value. The simplified table schema:

C(c_id, mostRecentDate)
L(l_id, c_id, theDate)

L.c_id is a foreign key reference to C.c_id.

Since

```
Select MAX(theDate)
FROM L
Group by L.c_id
```

Gives the max date for each c_id, I attempted to update via

```
UPDATE C
SET C.mostRecentDate= (SELECT Max(theDate)
FROM L
Where L.c_id = C.c_id
Group by L.c_id)
```

But this query does nothing (no errors generated, no rows updated). I am using MS Access 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works in Access 2007.  I think it should work in 2003 also.

```
UPDATE C
SET mostRecentDate = DMax("theDate", "L", "c_id = " & C.c_id);
```

Beware, if you have a c_id value in C which is not present in L, mostRecentDate will be replaced by Null for that row in C.  If you want to prevent that, it will take more work.

However I don't see the value of storing those max date values in table C.  You already know you can can retrieve them from table L any time you need them with a GROUP BY query of L.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I did not think of using an Access function within the SQL. As for why I am storing the max date, it is in order to avoid having to do another join. The max date will be displayed to the user in a data sheet that is populated using a query with quite a few joins already, and the time complexity of a join is bad. I decided to sacrifice non-redundant storage for speed in this case.

Comment: You're welcome.  UPDATE statements can be challenging in Access; many attempts trigger "must use an updateable query" error message.  The domain functions (DMax, DMin, DLookup, etc.) can be useful workarounds for some of those situations.

Answer (score 3):

Group by in subquery is not needed here. Try this:

```
UPDATE C
SET C.mostRecentDate= (SELECT Max(theDate)
FROM L
Where L.c_id = C.c_id)
```

Comment: this fails in 2003, you get the operation must use an updatable query message